# Google Search—set search language

Tags: google-search, localization

When I'm searching on Google, I usually use English. But sometimes I need results in a specific language only (Czech).

So I checked it in settings:
[image]

But when I want to search, I now have only two choices: “Search the web” and “Search English and Czech”.
[image]

Is there a way to add the option “Search Czech pages” without changing the global language and setting parameters manually in the URL?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible to just search in Czech. Here are the steps:

1. Open Google in your browser.
2. Type in your search query into the box and press enter.
3. Click on the address bar, get the cursor to the end of the URL and append `&lr=lang_cs` to it.
4. Press enter to "visit the URL" and you have your search results in Czech.

For the sake of other people reading this, the "cs" at the end of the URL is the ISO639 language code for Czech. English is "en" and other languages have their own language code too (e.g. German is "de" and Japanese is "ja"). Just change the "cs" part of the URL to the language that fits you best.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for answer! Actually this is the way how I'm doing it now. I'm just wondering if there's a way how to have the option “Search Czech pages” since I would expect it there after checking that language in settings. Rewriting the url everytime is pretty annoying, but it seems like there's no other option.

Comment: @Micer See [my answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/172380/88163) to [How to set language with Google advanced search operator?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/172373/88163)

Comment: @Rubén wow my comment is more than 10 years old, I don't remember asking this question. I don't even use Google for search anymore. Thanks anyway, your answer looks useful!

Comment: @Micer Some questions are bumped by Community User,  indirectly by recent questions as they appear on the Related widget on the side panel, etc. Anyway, thanks for your reply. It's nice to know you are still active, even if that was just because you got a notification.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try to change the big select saying "Which language should Google products use? English"?

At the moment it's set to English for you, and in addition you get Czech results aswell. Set it to Czech and English should be removed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer! Yes, I tried that, but then what if I want to search in Czech only? I'll not have such option (except editing url parameters).